# Grep element from variable?

Tags: ruby, file, grep

I need to extract an element using a regular expression.

First I'm reading a file from a function, then from a second function I'm reading another file and extract a value.

When processing the read of the second function, I grep the value from the first file:

```
#function read file
def get_file_as_string(filename)
  data = ''
  f = File.open(filename, "r") 
  f.each_line do |line|
    data += line
  end
  return data
end
```

Main:

```
file.each do |filename|
  lunsrvfile = 'server_lun.csv'
  ldev = get_file_as_string lunsrvfile
  f=File.read(filename)
  lunid = f.scan(/^"No.","time","(\h+:\h+:\h+).*/).flatten  #it's ok:  ex: 00:02:00
       if (ldev =~ /#{lunid}/) then
           server = ldev.lines.grep(lunid) #--> don't work
           #server = %x[grep lunid 'server_lun.csv' |awk -F ";" '{print $1}'] #--> don't work
           puts filename
           puts lunid
           puts server
    end
end
```

server_lun.csv:

```
server1;00:02:00
server2;00:03:25
server3;00:03:26
```

## Thx for your answer:

yes, i aldready test it, but when i put

```
server = ldev.lines.grep(/#{lunid}/)
```

all the file(lunsrvfile) is listed.

If match i need the first value: server1 for exemple

## Thx for your answer2:

but with:

```
server = ldev.grep(/#{lunid}/).first.split(';').first
```

Only the first server1 is print.

output:

```
filename1
lunid1
server1

filename2
lunid2
server1
(...)
```

Comment: You can't "extract an element from a grep". It's important that you take time to carefully word your question so it asks the question you want to ask, in a way that simply and concisely gets it across. Also, don't type like you're sending a text message, use correct grammar and spelling. Stack Overflow's goal is to provide encyclopedia-like Q&A.

Comment: But just think of how much more information we could store if we shortened everything.

Comment: can you show what a typical string in /lunid/ would be?  not sure what the contents of the file you are passing into filename is

Comment: your `get_file_as_string` is stripping new lines and just making it one big string.  if you the open(..).read method it will return it as lines.  I am pretty sure if you inspect `ldev` or look at `ldev.lines.count` it is probably 1 line

Answer (score 1):

`grep` requires a RegExp, you are passing it a string.   The same way you did for `=~`  you can do for the `grep` command.  Also you don't need to implement the `get_file_as_string`. The one liner at the top will do it for you.

I think this will do what you want:

```
lunsrvfile = 'server_lun.csv'
ldev = File.open(lunsrvfile, "rb").read

file.each do |filename|
  f = File.read(filename)
  lunid = f.scan(/^"No.","time","(\h+:\h+:\h+).*/).flatten  #it's ok:  ex: 00:02:00
  if (ldev =~ /#{lunid}/) then
    server = ldev.lines.grep(/#{lunid}/)
    puts filename
    puts lunid
    puts server
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read file into array this way

```
ldev = IO.readlines lunsrvfile
```

Then

```
ldev.grep /#{lunid}/
```

will return only string with that server

To get just server name you can try for example:

```
ldev.grep(/#{lunid}/).first.split(';').first
```

Comment: thx for your answer, but the grep take only the first server: server1 for each matching value.

Comment: This means, that your file is not divided into lines. Can you make `puts ldev.inspect` to see if its true?